# How to assign a reference of `System.out.println` to a variable?

Tags: java

I want to assign the reference to variable p:

```
Function<?, Void> p = System.out::println; // [1]
```

so that I can use it like:

```
p("Hello world"); // I wish `p` to behave exactly same as `System.out.println`
```

Expression [1] produce a compilation error, how to resolve it?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> The type of println(Object) from the type PrintStream is void, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: Void

If change `Void` to `void` the error becomes:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType

Comment: You can not *alias* a method in Java. Either you save `System.out` in a `PrintWriter` variable, such as `PrintWriter p = System.out;` with `p.println("Hello World");`, or you create an instance of a functional interface using method references or lambdas `Consumer<Object> p = System.out::println;`. But then you still need to call the method of the functional interface, so `p.accept("Hello World");`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't put all the overloads of `System.out.println` into one variable, which is what you seem to be trying to do here. Also, you should use the functional interface `Consumer` instead of `Function`.

You can store the most generic `System.out.println` overload, which is the one that takes an `Object`, in a `Consumer<Object>`:

```
Consumer<Object> println = System.out::println;
println.accept("Hello World!");
```

Or if you just want the overload that accepts a `String`,

```
Consumer<String> println = System.out::println;
```

Note that it is impossible to achieve the syntax you want (`print("Hello World")` directly) with functional interfaces.

Also note that if you pass a `char[]` to `println.accept`, it will not behave the same way as `System.out.println(char[])`. If this bothers you, you can instead use a static import:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

And then you can do:

```
out.println(...);
```

Comment: Actually `Object` will hide all power of compilation check of `println()`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Yeah, but you can't put all overloads into a single variable, can you?

Comment: @Sweeper - Still, given the question is using a string, I'd at least show `Consumer<String>` version first.

Comment: `Consumer<String> println = System.out::println;` and use `String.format()` if you need smth. more

Comment: This works for everything but `println(char[])` which is perhaps an obscure use case. i.e. println(Object x) prints `x.toString()` which is useless for a `char[]`.

Comment: hi can you explain why we '**can't  put all the overloads of System.out.println into one variable**'?

Comment: @dongjy Functional interfaces only represent one kind of method signature. So to store all those overloads, you would need many variables of functional interfaces. You'll need a `Consumer<String>`, `IntConsumer`, `DoubleConsumer`, just to name a few. You'll also need to create your own `CharArrayConsumer`, `CharConsumer` etc. since those don't exist. In short, it's a limitation of the language.

Comment: @dongjy The interface `Consumer<String>` offers one method with the signature `void accept(String obj)`. So you can only call it with `String`, not `int` or anything else. It does not alias the method, it rather creates an instance of the `Consumer<String>` interface which, upon call of `accept`, calls `System.out.println(obj)` with the given argument, so a `String`. I suggest you read about functional interfaces and method references.

Answer (score 3):

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.println("helo world");
```

Why don't just save `System.out` into variable and then use it?

Another solution, to not loose compilation time check for `println()`, is use `String.format()` function. You can add it to the variable:

```
BiConsumer<String, Object> println = (format, args) -> System.out.println(String.format(format, args));
println.accept("hello world", null);
```